# Nuget Hint Path fails to restore

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have a project

```
sln
- Folder1
  - MyProj.csproj

-..Other projects and folders
```

I add a nuget package to 'MyProj', which results in the following in the csproj

```
<Reference Include="ANUGETPACKAGE, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\ANUGETPACKAGE.2.0.0\lib\net35\ANUGETPACKAGE.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Then I merge that code into my 'Main' branch which has the same structure setup as Development. The reference is now broken. Nuget fails to restore and fix the reference. I uninstall and re-install package and it results in the same except for:

```
<HintPath>packages\ANUGETPACKAGE.2.0.0\lib\net35\ANUGETPACKAGE.dll</HintPath>
```

How can I be sure that the path to the package will work in both branches?
(VS2015 Update 2, Nuget 3.4.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reference is now broken. Nuget fails to restore and fix the reference

This is because the relative path of the package are different in the both branches, the HintPath will be different, then the reference was broken.

> How can I be sure that the path to the package will work in both branches?

If you want to make sure the path of the package will work in both branches, you could define a **absolute path** of repositoryPath in the NuGet.config in both branches. You can following the below steps to set it:

1. Right click on the solution->Add->New Item...
2. Select the Text file and rename to NuGet.config
3. Add content like this inside the NuGet.config file:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <config>
       <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\packages" />
     </config>
   </configuration>`

Then reboot Visual Studio and it should work. The path to the package will work in both branches.

Hope this can help you.